# How to configure SQLite in Tomcat 6?

Tags: java, sqlite, tomcat, jdbc

Can you please provide the steps on how to use sqlite in tomcat 6? I am using Xerial sqlite jdbc driver. In my application, I have got multiple sqlite databases (.db files) and would need to connect to a different sqlite database depending on what user logs in ? Where can I put all the .db files - with in the webapp root's directory or any where on the system or with in WEB-INF?

Thanks,

Deep

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What we did is pretty similar. Unfortunately you cannot create a SQLite Connection pool on Tomcat as SQLite has a database file for each user.

Just copy the jar file in `TOMCAT_HOME/lib` folder but you cannot call a connection via JNDI. 
You will have to do something like this:

```
/**
     * 
     * @param driverClassName
     * @param url
     * @param user
     * @param password
     * @throws SQLException 
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public DefaultJdbcTransaction(String driverClassName, String url, String user, String password) throws SQLException {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        try {
            Class.forName(driverClassName).newInstance();

            if (user == null && password == null) {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            } else {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            }
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            throw new SQLException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            throw new SQLException(e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            throw new SQLException(e);
        }
    }
```

Where `url="jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/sqlite/file/userId.db"`, `driverClassName="org.sqlite.JDBC"`, and (`user = password = null`).

I'm using `sqlitejdbc-v056.jar`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. If I can't use the connection pooling offered by Tomcat then can multiple users connect to the same .db file or do I need to implement some sort of basic connection pooling since multiple users could end up connecting to the same db at the same time ?

Comment: If multiple users will connect to the same db file, then connection pooling is possible otherwise, you're wasting time.

Answer (score 9):

I just went through configuring sqlite3 with Tomcat 7. Everything is working now, so thought I'd share my setup. 
- Download the JDBC driver (org.sqlite.JDBC) that lives in sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar (or whatever the latest version is). https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads 
 and copy it to yourTomcat/lib 
- You can copy the sqlite db anywhere you want to. For my setup, I created a 'dbs' directory under my tomcat install, and put it there.

Now set up your app. If you don't have a META-INF/context.xml file, then create one. This is a minimal file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>  
  <Resource name="jdbc/yourdb" 
            auth="Container" 
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            driverClassName="org.sqlite.JDBC"
            url="jdbc:sqlite:/${catalina.home}/dbs/yourDB.db"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory">
  </Resource>
</Context>
```

Then add the following to WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>Reviews Database</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/yourdb</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

At this point, you should be good to go. Here is some sample code for accessing the database (I have a table 'admin' with a column 'username'):

```
public String getName() {
    LOG.info("getting name : " + this.name);
    try {
          Context ctx = new InitialContext();
          DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/yourdb");
          Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
          Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select username from admin");
          this.name = rs.getString(1);
    } catch (SQLException se) {
          LOG.info(se.toString());
    } catch (NamingException ne) {
          LOG.info(ne.toString());
    }
    return this.name;
}
```

Note: some distros of tomcat don't come with tomcat.dbcp by default, if you run into problems it may be easier to reference the dbcp class that comes with commons, org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory. I had this problem with tomcat.dbcp not included in my tomcat7 installation and once I switched the reference in context.xml everything was working fine.

Comment: just for info : on tomcat 8 => factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory"