# Java - sqlite db file cannot be found

Tags: java, sqlite, tomcat, jdbc

***Comment on the edit***: I think I had already fixed my original issue (driver could not be found) and now I have the following problem:

***EDIT 2***: when I replace the `url` in `context.xml` with the full path (`url=jdbc:sqlite:C:/Dev/workspace/jerseyrestdemo/resources/greetings.sqlite`) it works. How can I now make that path relative??

***EDIT 3***: I followed the instructions in[how to configure JNDI datasource for db connection in tomcat](http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/configuring-jndi-datasource-for-database-connection-pooling-in-tomcat): 1. Delete my project-specific context.xml and put the content into `tomcat7/conf/context.xml`. There I specified the namespace `name=jdbc/greetings.sqlite`

```
<Resource name="jdbc/greetings.sqlite" 
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        maxActive="100"
        maxIdle="30"
        maxWait="10000"
        driverClassName="org.sqlite.JDBC"
        url="jdbc:sqlite:resources/greetings.sqlite"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory">
 </Resource>
```

2. In the DAO class I get the connection via

   `Context initCtx = new InitialContext();`
   `Context envCtx  = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");`
   `DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/greetings.sqlite");`
   `conn = ds.getConnection();`

But I still get the error `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (path to 'resources/greetings.sqlite': 'C:\Dev\eclipse\resources' does not exist)`

***EDIT 4***: In the end, I go for storing the db file in the catalina home
`/${catalina.home}/databases/greetings.sqlite` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13261148/5379182). I guess you shouldn't store your db files in the web app project anyways

---

I have a SQLite db file in `resources/greetings.sqlite` under my project folder but when I run my webapp on tomcat it cannot find the db file:

```
java.sql.SQLException: path to 'resources/greetings.sqlite': 'C:\Dev\eclipse\resources' does not exist
at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:192)
at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:76)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:25)
at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:24)
at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
at demo.rest.jersey.spring.dao.JdbcGreetingDAO.getRowCount(JdbcGreetingDAO.java:29)
at demo.rest.jersey.spring.GreetingService.randomGreeting(GreetingService.java:29)
at demo.rest.jersey.spring.GreetingService.greet(GreetingService.java:18)
at demo.rest.jersey.spring.SpringRequestResource.getHello(SpringRequestResource.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

I have copied the jdbc jar into the tomcat/lib directory and added the code below in `META-INF/context.xml` and `WEB-INF/web.xml`.

This is what I put into my web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
<description>Greetings Database</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/greetings.sqlite</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

and I have created a file in `WebContent/META-INF/context.xml`. I assume the relative path in the `url` field of the `Resource` is not how it should be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>  
  <Resource name="jdbc/greetings.sqlite" 
            auth="Container" 
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            driverClassName="org.sqlite.JDBC"
            url="jdbc:sqlite:resources/greetings.sqlite"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory">
  </Resource>
</Context>
```

What I would like to avoid is putting the db file in a tomcat subdir but just make it part of the project, so others don't have to bother moving the file to their tomcat dir.

---

Here is the DAO class

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class JdbcGreetingDAO implements GreetingDAO 
{

private Connection getConn() throws SQLException
{
    Connection conn = null;
    try
    {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/greetings.sqlite");
        conn = ds.getConnection();
    }
    catch(NamingException ne)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot get connection");
        ne.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
}


@Override
public void insert(String greeting) throws SQLException
{
    Connection conn = getConn();
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    st.executeUpdate(String.format("INSERT INTO greetings (greeting) VALUES (%s)", greeting));
}    
}
```

The DAO is used by a `GreetingsService`

```
public class GreetingService 
{
@Autowired
private JdbcGreetingDAO dataSource;

public String addGreeting(String greeting) throws SQLException
{
    dataSource.insert(greeting);
    return greeting;
}
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is `C:\Dev\eclipse\resources` and does it correspond to a real path on the deployment server?  Looks like you may have a hardcoded (or configured) path valid on the dev machine but not on the server.  Also the exception does not appear to be "No suitable driver".

Comment: Your title does not match your actual question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize the error message is a new one. Apparently the driver issue is resolved